# from ticket.ticketapp import views ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ticket.ticketapp'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Just started working with Django. I created an app, mapped it on INSTALLED_APPS list and wrote a simple function in views.py. but getuser() method in the views.py not able to import in the urls.py

`**models.py**

`class user(models.Model): username = models.CharField(max_length=255) password = models.CharField(max_length=255) email = models.EmailField()`

```
`**views.py**
`from django.shortcuts import render
from models import user
from django.http import JsonResponse

def getuser(request):
    data = user.objects.all()

    return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)``
```

**urls.py**

```
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from ticket.ticketapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('airline/', views.getuser())
]`
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY77W.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAIe3.png)

from ticket.ticketapp import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ticket.ticketapp'`

Answer (score 0):

In django it is relative

```
from . import views
```

Comment: No i  have tried this but not working